# When are eigenvalues of $A+A^T$ all positive?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $A$ is a square real-valued matrix, which restrictions on $A$ guarantee that all eigenvalues of $A+A^T$ are positive?

Comment: What about the restriction $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$? Sorry I couldn't help myself... More seriously, what exactly are you looking for? *Any old* condition that guarantees what you want? Or some sort of "minimal required conditions"?

Comment: It's true if $Ax$ and $x$ form an acute angle for every $x$.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow looking for easy to interpret necessary+sufficient conditions on $A$ that guarantee this

Comment: This may have no simple answer. The matrices $A_x=\pmatrix{1&x\cr0&2\cr}$ all have the same eigenvalues, but $A+A^T$ has just positive eigenvalues if and only if $x^2<8$.

Comment: There might be something useful at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52578/eigenvalues-of-sum-of-a-non-symmetric-matrix-and-its-transpose-aat

Comment: One interesting connection (page 37 of [slides](https://cscproxy.mpi-magdeburg.mpg.de/mpcsc/events/trogir/slides/psa_slides.pdf)) is that range of eigenvalues of A+A' is determined by real part of numeric range of A, so wondering if condition can be reformulated in terms of real part of eigs of A

Comment: If $A$ is definite positive then... $A+A^T$ will also be positive definite... maybe not the most useful comment!

Comment: @TheoBendit It’s equivalent, so “if and only if”.

Comment: Empirically it seems that if any eigenvalue of $A$ has a negative real part, then  $A+A'$ will have a negative eigenvalue [plot](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-negative-eigs.nb)

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov It is indeed the case that if $A + A'$ has only positive eigenvalues, then all eigenvalues of $A$ have a positive real part, as you have empirically verified. The converse does not hold, though

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov You might find that the [Gershgorin Circle theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem) leads to some useful conditions